# Open a hidden jFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I am new to Java Standalone Application Development.
In my code I am using below code sample to move from one jFrame to another.

```
        AdminSetiings adminSettings = new AdminSetiings();
        this.hide();
        adminSettings.setVisible(true);
```

There are some variables such as username, is using in the current jFrame which is MainPage. When I Use the same code to get back to my MainPage it doesn't have that values(username) in that jFrame because they are passed from another jFrame(Login jFrame).

So I want to show the MainPage which has that data(the one I hide before). Can someone please help me with this.

P.S. - I am familiar with visual studio stand alone applications and it provides a function to open a form as a dialog form which allows me to keep the main form running. That is exactly what I want to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to wrap your initial UI opening in an EventQueue invocation.

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
    new Login().setVisible(true);
});
```

Once you've received your credentials, you can call the *hide* method in JFrame on the login page and then instantiate and show your new JFrame, AdminSettings, with just *new AdminSettings().setVisible(true);*